# Stack drone images in IDL_overlap degree

Tags: image, stack, overlap, idl-programming-language

I have about 6000 aerial images taken by 3DR drone for vegetation sites.

The images have to overlap to some extant because the drone flights cover the area go from EW and then again NS, so the images present the same area from two directions. I need the overlap for the images for extra accuracy.

I don't know to write a code on IDL to combine the images and create that overlap. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: This is a non-trivial problem. I am not aware of any library routine that would help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something that is identifiable that occurs in both images. Preferably you would have several things across the field of view so that you could get the correct rotation as well as a simple x-y shift.
The basic steps you will need to follow are:

1. Source Identification - Identify sources in all images that will later be used to align the images. Make sure the centering of these soruces are good so that they will align better later.
2. Basic alignment. Start with a guess on where the images should align then try to match the sources.
3. Match the sources. There are several libraries that can do this for stars (in astronomical images) that could be adapted for this.
4. Shift and rotate the images. This can be done to the pixels or to the header that is read in and have a program manipulate the pixels on the fly.